# SQL request for a JSON file

Tags: sql, grafana, influxdb

I am using node-red and influxDB with it. Basically I am running node-red (which execute a python code), with node-red I am getting a data from gauge strain cell, and I have them with a json format as follows :

```
{ “X” : “-0.18102575652004627”,“Y” : “0.8599837901151595”}
```

That data is stored inside influxDB, then I would like to display them in Grafana. The X value will be the X axis and Y value the Y axis.

How can I make a SQL query request to get X and Y independently.

When I use :

```
SELECT * FROM
```

I get this data as a result:

```
1574439673173046787 { "X" : "0.5331351951053145","Y" : "0.5351730541177269"}
1574439674038377239 { "X" : "0.23836196817466518","Y" : "0.2391236764227406"}
1574439676107561878 { "X" : "-0.6959993930530565","Y" : "-0.6942994126488101"}
```

which is the timestamp for each acquisition. But I do find a way to select only X for example for a given timestamp.

Thank you

Comment: What is the column name of the JSON column? Generally you would use ->> to get a specific field in a JSON column. ie if the column was called info, you would use `select info->>'x' from data`

Comment: I am not sure what is the name of the column. Should I define it myself ? My JSON actually is only this { “X” : “-0.18102575652004627”,“Y” : “0.8599837901151595”}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) InfluxDB doesn't support SQL, but InfluxQL (syntax is similar, but it is not a SQL).
Please check InfluxDB doc for correct time condition syntax - there is a few options (absolute/relative): https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/data_exploration/#time-syntax

2.) It looks like your `X`, `Y` are a `tags`, but Grafana needs fields. Only fields can be visualized. Tags are used for filtering. You should to change measurement schema/node-red code.

3.) Grafana supports timeseries data by default. `X value will be the X axis and Y value the Y axis` - it doesn't look like a timeseries visualization. You will have problem to do this type of graph in Grafana. You may will need to code own custom panel for that.

Comment: For 3), can I create a custom panel of this type in Grafana ? If not, do you know some tech / where I can make a custom interface with my X and Y daa coming from node red ? Thank you